# mysql добавить столбец с сегодняшней датой

Tags: mysql, дата

Привет, необходимо добавить в таблицу Tempvigruzka столбец dates с сегодняшней датой
Пробовал 'Alter table tempvigruzka add dates datetime' но он вводит пустые значения

Comment: Еще потом надо из tempvigruzka добавить все уникальные строки в таблицу vigruzka

Comment: Вопрос решился, добавил в vigruzka 'OrderDate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()' и потом с помощью Insert into vigruzka (User_Name0, Name0, DisplayName0, Publisher0, Version0, LastW, IP_Adress) select * from tempvigruzka; перенес данные